# on google search, website does not shows any description?

Tags: robots.txt

When we search by company name on google it shows our website name but does not provide any information.

[image]

then I tried to fix this issue by editing robots.txt file.

```
User-agent: *

Disallow:

Sitemap: {{ site.url }}/sitemap.xml
```

Is there any other method to solve this?
how can I get the information on google search?

Answer (score 0):

Add metadata to your HTML page.

```
    <head> 
       <meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />
       ...some other stuff
    <head/>

<body>
  the content of your web site
<body/>
```

[see docs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)